# Create Record Functionality Not Working in Express App with MongoDB and Expo Go

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, axios, expo-go

I'm developing a React Native app using Expo Go and have an Express backend connected to MongoDB. My login and signup functionality work perfectly with Axios, but I'm facing issues with the create record functionality. When I attempt to create a record via a POST request, there's no error on the server, and no data appears in my MongoDB collection.

```
app.post("/record", async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const { name, genres, techniques, type } = req.body;
const recordsCollection = client.db("frefury").collection("records");
const result = await recordsCollection.insertOne({
name,
genres,
techniques,
type,
});
res.status(201).json({ message: "Record created", recordId: result.insertedId });
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error:", error);
res.status(500).json({ message: "boo" });
}
});
```

my handlesubmit code:

```
const handleSubmit = async () =\> {
try {
// Prepare data to send, excluding the PDF fi

            // Make the POST request
            const response = await axios.post("http://myipwashere/record", {
                name: record.name,
                genres: record.genres,
                techniques: record.techniques,
                type: record.type,
            });
    
            // Handle success
            setSubmissionSuccess(true);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };
```

Here's what I've verified and confirmed so far:

```
MongoDB Atlas cluster is active and accessible.
Network access for my IP is enabled in MongoDB Atlas.
My React Native app is running on Expo Go, and I'm testing on a physical device.
The server is running locally and accessible via my local network IP.
CORS is correctly configured in my Express app.
Login and signup routes work fine, so POST requests in general are working.
```